# Excerpt outside loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to get excerpt outside loop, but turns out it's not that simple as first thought. The excerpt should echo the text before the more tag. Meaning I have not set a specific maximum amount of letters the excerpt should include. This is because I don't want the sentences to stop in the middle of them.

I have set the post id to the following:

```
<?php $post_id = 27; ?>
```

Then, I have tried adding different functions. These are both found on StackOverflow and Google. But for some reason I can't get them to work. I suspect some of them are old and that WordPress has changed since then.

**First try:**

```
function get_excerpt_by_id( $post_id = 27 ) {
    global $post;
    $save_post = $post;
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $post = $save_post;
    wp_reset_postdata( $post );
    return $excerpt;
}
```

**Second try:**

```
function my_excerpt($post_id) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if ($post->post_excerpt) {
        // excerpt set, return it
        return apply_filters('the_excerpt', $the_post->post_excerpt);

    } else {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $excerpt;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how this should be solved?

Edit:

```
<?php $post_id = 27; // Endre denne ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id("$post_id"), full); ?>

            <div style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1><?php echo get_the_title("$post_id");?></h1>
                    <div>
                    <?php get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $post_id ); ?>
                    <?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $post_id ) ?> 
                    <?php echo $excerpt; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink("$post_id");?>" rel="" id="trykklink" class="btn btn-outline-fill-white littluft nomarginleft" role="button" title="" onmouseover="this.title='';">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>   
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: How about try passing the post_id directly into get_the_excerpt( $post_id )

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
<?php get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $post_id ); ?>
```

for more information please check [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $post ) ?>
```

`$post` can be the post id or the $post object.

[From WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for such a late answer. Tested you code, and found out it didnt work...

Comment: @Olen This works 100%... What is your $post variable?